# Colas en C: ¿Existe una forma de volver a insertar información en un nodo?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, estructuras, queue

el problema que tengo es que quiero insertar más información en un nodo después de ordenar la cola de forma ascendente, pero no encuentro la forma de volver a insertar datos en  el nodo ya existente, ¿comó podría solucionar el problema?
La intención del código es que quiero primero que me ordene las calificaciones de mayor a menor, ya una vez ordenadas insertar los demás datos del struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
//Datos del alumno
struct alumnos
{
    int calificacion;
    char * nombre;
    char * apellido;
} ;
typedef struct nodo* Cola;
//Struct Nodo
struct nodo
{
    struct alumnos Datos;
    Cola siguiente;
};
```

Y esta es mi función de insertar los datos para ordenar de menor a mayor la cola:

```
void PushCalificaciones(Cola * q, int calificacion)
{
    if((*q) == NULL)
    {
        (*q)=(Cola)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
        (*q)->Datos.calificacion = calificacion;
        (*q)->siguiente = NULL;
    }
    else{
        Cola anterior =NULL;
        Cola primero = (*q);
        while ((*q)!= NULL && (*q)->Datos.calificacion > calificacion)
        {
            anterior=(*q);
            (*q)=(*q)->siguiente;
        }
        if((*q)==NULL)
        {
            (*q)=(Cola)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
            (*q)->Datos.calificacion=calificacion;
            (*q)->siguiente = NULL;
            anterior->siguiente=(*q);
            (*q)=primero;
        }
        else if((*q)->Datos.calificacion <= calificacion)
        {
            if(anterior==NULL) //Hacemos la comprobamos que el elemento es mayor
            {
                anterior = (Cola)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
                anterior->Datos.calificacion = calificacion;
                anterior->siguiente = (*q);
                (*q)= anterior;
            }
            else{
                Cola aux;
                aux = (Cola)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
                aux->Datos.calificacion = calificacion;
                anterior->siguiente=aux;
                aux->siguiente =  (*q);
                (*q)=primero;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y asi queda la función donde se insertaran los demás datos (la cuál no inserta los datos en el nodo ya creado):

```
void PushNombres(Cola * q, char Nombre[30], char Apellido[30])
{
    Cola aux = (*q);
    Cola anterior = NULL;
    while ((*q)!= NULL)
    {
        anterior = (*q);
        (*q) = (*q) -> siguiente;
    }
    (*q) = (Cola)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    (*q)->Datos.nombre = strdup(Nombre);
    (*q)->Datos.apellido = strdup(Apellido);
    (*q)->siguiente = (*q);
    anterior->siguiente = (*q);
    (*q)=aux;
}
```

Comment: y por que no insertas esa información nombre y apellido desde el principio junto con la calificación?  así no tienes que volver a recorrer los datos para reinsertarles mas datos

Comment: La idea principal es que ordene las calificaciones de mayor a menor, para que acabando de pedir loas calificaciones se pida en ese orden los nombres y apellidos.